# Does div tag autowrapp child items

Tags: html

I was testing on how to make a responsive design UI. There came this problem. I thought div's default behavior was to wrap the child items and their total width becomes the div's width.

Link to JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/adithyavr/jEEd4/

In the above example see **#search_area**. This div's width is supposed to conform to inner text box and the search box. But it is taking the width of the HTML tag that is 1280 px. W

```
  #search_area{
            height: 100%;
            position:relative;
            left:50%;
            top:20%;
           }
```

Why is this specefic error happening. A hint will help me.

thanks in advance. Below is the screenshot for the problem.

[image]

Comment: No its not, inspect your element with firebug or any other inspector

Comment: It is therefore I have posted the question. Also i have added screenshot now for the same. Please check. It is happening both in firefox and IE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your css

```
#header_area{
 background:#B50E24;
 width:100%;
 height:10%;
}
```

you have specified `width:100%` hence it'll occupy 100% width.

Apart from that, `<div>` is a `block` element. `block` elements takes the full available width. If you want it to wrap the whole content only, give `display: inline-block`

Comment: Just to clarify, div by default will expand max available width even if there are only 200px worth children? The reason is because it is set to display: block by default?

Comment: A block element is an element that takes up the full width available, and has a line break before and after it. - http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_display_visibility.asp